# D3 force diagram - how to trigger event when nodes stop repositioning

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have a force diagram where the nodes move around for a few seconds after initial load.  How can I trigger an event when the nodes have stopped moving and reached stasis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented for version 3 [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#on) and version 4 [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_on).

Essentially for both it's:

```
.on('end', someCallback)
```